# Firestore - How to get data from an array field in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem on how I will get the data/value from the field which is an array. Please see image:

[image]

In the image, I want to get the data/value of `parking_code` which is from the `array field (parkings)`.
I tried this one:

```
parking2 = db.collection(u'parking').document().get({u'parkings.parking_code'})
```

but it returns me like this: `<google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot object at 0x0000014925256550>`

I also tried this kind of code:

```
parking2 = db.collection(u'parking').document().get({u'parkings.parking_code'}).to_dict()
```

but it returns a `None` value. Anyone who has solution on this or at least just an idea, please I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

> A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Cloud
>   Firestore database. The data can be extracted with the getData() or
>   get(String) methods.
>
> If the DocumentSnapshot points to a non-existing document, getData()
>   and its corresponding methods will return null. You can always
>   explicitly check for a document's existence by calling exists().

Answer (score 0):

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'parking').document(u'D7k...')

doc = doc_ref.get()
print(doc.to_dict())
```

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#custom_objects